# how i can update next middleware, so when user is logged in and try to visit loginPages (ie, login, register) they will redirect to dashboard

Tags: next.js, middleware

```js
import {withAuth} from 'next-auth/middleware';
import createIntlMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const locales = ['en'];
const protectedPages = ['/dashboard'];
const loginPages = ['/login', '/register'];

const testPagePath = (pages, pathname) => {

 const pathnameRegex = RegExp(
      `^(/(${locales.join('|')}))?(${pages.join('|')})?$`,
      'i'
  );

  return pathnameRegex.test(pathname);

}

const intlMiddleware = createIntlMiddleware({
    locales,
    defaultLocale: 'en'
  });

const authMiddleware = withAuth(
// Note that this callback is only invoked if
// the `authorized` callback has returned `true`
// and not for pages listed in `pages`.
    function onSuccess(req) {
        return intlMiddleware(req);
    },
    {
        callbacks: {
            authorized: ({token}) =>  token != null
        },
        pages: {
            signIn: '/login'
        }
    }
);
  
export default function middleware(req) {
    
    if (!testPagePath(protectedPages, req.nextUrl.pathname)) {
      return intlMiddleware(req);
    } else {
      return (authMiddleware)(req);
    }
  }
 
export const config = {
  // Skip all paths that should not be internationalized. This example skips the
  // folders "api", "_next" and all files with an extension (e.g. favicon.ico)
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)']
};
```

i want to user redirect to dashboard pages if they have logged in, i am using next auth, for prorected routes i have created function, but for login, register page i want to redirect them to dashboard if already logged in.